# Angular component not being added to element

Tags: angular

I have a child component that is added to parent component dynamically . 
here is my parent html:

```
<button (click)="addHtml()">add html</button>
<div #list></div>
```

and this is my parent component

```
export class LogComponent {

  @ViewChild('list', {read: ViewContainerRef}) list: ViewContainerRef;

  private addHtml(log: Log) {
    var cf = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ItemComponent)
    let res = this.list.createComponent(cf)
  }

}
```

but the child components are added at the end of parent html and not the #list element, why?
thanks in advance

Comment: It works fine for me. Did you include `ItemComponent` in `entryComponents` array?

Comment: @yurzui really??? cause I'm banging my head against the wall trying to understand what am I doing wrong. can you post your code in plunker or something?

Comment: Yes, one minute :) https://plnkr.co/edit/56WdLcgOorJRJwXCJhaD?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui see in the plunker the child is not added to the div, but appended after the #list

Comment: It's by design. If you want to put it inside div then use `template` or `ng-container` https://plnkr.co/edit/eSdknsw2QztyJCDIM9qw?p=preview

Comment: See also why it is added after #list https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9035

Comment: @yurzui ok thanks a lot, you'r a life saver, and just for your extremely helpful comment, if you wish, post as answer so I can vote up and make as the correct answer, also i'm gonna vote up every answer you have ever posted, well not all but like 10 of them ;)